# Correr aplicación Windows Form en Sistema Operativo Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, macos

Buenos días,

Tengo una aplicación que desarrolle hace un tiempo, y la elabore mediante Visual Studio .Net C#.

Sin embargo ahora me solicitan instalarla en un Equipo Mac.

Esto es posible, se puede hacer un render de la aplicación para correrla en este equipo.?

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Tal como está, la respuesta es no. Puedes intentar con Mono, aunque creo que el soporte winforms en mac es limitado. Por otro lado, existe una librería llamada [eto.forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto) que si parece que funciona en Mac, pero por supuesto deberás modificar tu aplicación original para hacer uso de dicha librería.

Comment: Checa este sitio:  https://www.visualstudio.com/es/vs/visual-studio-mac/

Comment: Excelente gracias @Pikoh, voy a probar con el software Mono.

Answer (score -1):

Para correr C# en un sistema operativo Macintosh puedes instalar `Parallels` y **virtualizar** `windows`  porque de otra manera podrias hacerlo correr pero no podrias compilar el proyecto esta es la mejor manera de hacerlo.